# why does my var/log/apache2/ directory have a bunch of folders named after IP addresses?

Tags: apache-2.2

Apache/vlogger question: why does my `var/log/apache2/` directory have a bunch of folders named after IP addresses? I'm running one virtual host listening to `*:80` should I change this to `[static ip address]:80`? I apologize in advance for any newbie-ness.

My logging configuration is as follow:

```
CustomLog "| /usr/sbin/vlogger -s access.log /var/log/apache2" combined
```

Comment: How did you configure Apache's logging?

Comment: `CustomLog "| /usr/sbin/vlogger -s access.log /var/log/apache2" combined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logs are split because of your configuration. From vlogger documentation:

> it takes piped output from apache, splits off the first field

...

> you need to add a "%v" as the first part of your logformat, like this:
>
> LogFormat "%v %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined

http://n0rp.chemlab.org/vlogger/

If you did not change your logformat or you changed it incorrectly and the client IP address is the first field of your log format, then vlogger will create a log file for each client's IP address.